# focus input within tabdoesn't work with focus()

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

focus on tab shown doesn't work this way, my js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(":input:visible").each(function () {
                $(this).focus();
            });

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="active" id="note-tab" ng-show="currentTab==1">
<form ng-submit="postStatus()">
<input placeholder="Your private notepad here.." class="status-input" type="text" 
ng-model="newItem" autofocus>
</form>
</div>

<div class="" id="quotes-tab" ng-show="currentTab==2">
<form ng-submit="postStatus()">
<input placeholder="Inspiring thoughts on your mind.." class="status-input" type="text"
ng-model="newItem" autofocus>
</form>
</div>

<div class="" id="project-tab" ng-show="currentTab==3">
<form ng-submit="postStatus()">
<input placeholder="Milestones you've accomplished.." class="status-input" type="text" ng-model="newItem" autofocus>
</form>
</div>

<div class="" id="skill-tab" ng-show="currentTab==4">
<form ng-submit="postStatus()">
<input placeholder="Skills that you've learned.." class="status-input" type="text"
ng-model="newItem" autofocus>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

At first at I thought my seach bar caused the problem, so I commented it out, but it doens't solve my problem.

Comment: can you please tell me what exactly u want??  and in your js code its not the correct statement as it will try to focus the each and every visible input and finally you will get the focus on last visible input type control

Comment: Your summary title does not matches with question body..Please update it

Answer (score 1):

you cannot focus all your inputs,you can do one of them

```
  $("input:visible:first").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input:text").each(function () {

            $(this).focus();
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input:visible").focus();
});
```